# Evaluate the equality of two series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

How can we show that these below expressions are not always equal

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2}a_{i}b_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{2}a_{i} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{2}b_{i} $$

I tried by inputting some numbers but for some reason I could not put my finger on it.

Comment: Did you try $a_i = b_i = 1$?

Comment: Dude, they are almost never equal. I find it harder to find solutions than counterexamples. Seriously, roll some dices and see how often they are equal.

Comment: perhaps my approach was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily spell this out: $\sum_{i=1}^2 a_ib_i = a_1b_1+a_2b_2$ whereas $\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i\cdot \sum_{i=1}^2 b_i=(a_1+a_2)(b_1+b_2)=a_1b_1+a_2b_1+a_1b_2+a_2b_2$. This suggests an epic fail if we let $a_1=b_2=0$, $a_2=b_1=1$. (Actually, its harder to find nontrivial examples that *don't* fail)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1b_1+a_2b_2=(a_1+a_2)(b_1+b_2)$. Then, we have $a_1b_2+a_2b_1=0$. So we can choose $a_1=a_2=b_1=b_2=1$.